# How do I stop JQuery location.reload loading more than once?

Tags: jquery

I am running a countdown clock. When the countdown finishes. I want to refresh the page once. I am using location.reload but it keeps loading and loading and loading. How to I break that loop?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#clock').countdown('<?php echo $tickets_pageRecord['sales_start_date']; ?>')
  .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    var format = '%H hr%!H %M min%!M %S  sec%!S';
    if(event.offset.totalDays > 0) {
      format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
    }
    if(event.offset.weeks > 0) {
      format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
    }
    $(this).html('Box Office opens in ');
    $(this).append(event.strftime(format));
  })
  .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
    $(this).html('<h3>Click on shopping cart to buy tickets</h3>');
    location.reload();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Use local storage to set a variable to save state.

Comment: localstorage is only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass some state so once you have reloaded, you don't run everything over again.

You can...

1. Add a query string parameter to tell your script not to run
2. Add a flag to one of the storage options (cookie, local storage, etc) that you can check to decide whether to run the script
3. If the page is materially different (you are refreshing because it is I assume) you could test for that difference

But even better than that - as you are running PHP on the server, if the time has already passed - just don't add the JavaScript as you don't need it anymore (it looks like you refresh when the box office is open).

Comment: The issue with using PHP as you suggest is that the user still has to refresh the page if they are sitting there counting down to the last second. I want the age to auto refresh and the links and shopping carts displayed. So PHP not quite what I need.

Comment: @TerryAlly - check the time on the server side, if it is before the time you add the script... if it is after the time you remove the script. That way the refresh doesn't happen once the box office is open. You may need a slight shim as client times won't be perfectly matched to your server time - so you might want to signal the time when you send the initial page.

Comment: I decided to combine with PHP as you suggested. But location.reload() was still firing, so I removed it and replaced with a redirection to the same URL and that worked. JQuery is really complicated!